# Proving $n! > n$ for $n > 2$ using mathematical induction

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

I have to prove $n<n!$ for all $n>2$ by mathematical induction.

I did it as follows. I proved the base case.

Then let it be true for $K>2$:

$$ K<K! $$

I have to prove,

$$ K+1<(K+1)! $$

$$ K<K! $$

Adding $1$ on both sides

$$ K+1<K!+1<(K+1)! $$

Hence

$$    K+1<(K+1)! $$

Is the last step I did ($K!+1<(K+1)!$) Right?

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should prove $K!+1<(K+1)!$ which is not so hard.

Comment: No. For the n=3 case, you just check if 3<3! which is true. Then assume for n=k case and prove for the n=k+1 case.

Comment: @KaratugOzanBircan: Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by n2?

Comment: @Rankeya: I guess, it should be $n>2.$

Comment: Then Akito's question reads "I have to prove $n > 2$ by mathematical induction", and this does not make sense either does it?

Comment: Akito what is the exact statement that you need to prove using induction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use induction at all when you can see plainly that $n! = n\cdot (n-1) \cdots 1 \ge n\cdot (n-1) > n$ if $n>2$ ?

If this is an exercise, it's a silly one. It's exercises like this that give a bad name to induction...

Comment: Amen. Though to be fair, exercises that specify an unreasonable method are hardly limited to induction, never mind exercises that specify a reasonable method when others would do as well.

Comment: or similarly $n! = n\cdots 2\cdot 1 \ge n\cdot 2 \gt n$ if $n \gt 2$, making it clearer why $2$ matters.

Comment: @Henry, sure. It proves something stronger than required but so does my argument, and mine provides a quadratic lower bound :-)

Answer (score 3):

Starting with $K \lt K!$,

multiplying both sides by $K+1 \gt 0$ you have $K(K+1) \lt (K+1)!$,

but since $K\gt 2$ you have $K+1 \lt K(K+1) $ and so  $K+1 \lt (K+1)!$

Answer (score 0):

Since in your case $K > 2$, the statement $K!+1 < (K+1)!$ is true. This is because $(K+1)! = K!(K+1) = K!K + K!$, and $K!K > 1$ for $K > 1$.